# Recommended table schema for role inheritence

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a laravel/php package for roles functionality

**Example Roles Required:**

```
blogger
worker
admin
    - inherits
        *    

department.manager
    - inherits
        department.*
    - passive-inherits
        department
department
    - inherits
        worker
department.blogger
    - inherits
        blogger
    - passive-inherits
        department
```

**Here's my problem:**

Usually many-to-many relationships are set out like this

`parent_role_id` | `child_role_id`

However I'm thinking, since some roles inherit with wildcards (*) eg: admin, department.manager, I can't (or can't fully) use this approach because wildcard's aren't roles...

### Would anyone have any ideas?

My solution: `parent_role_id` | `child_role_id` table + `parent_role_id` | `wildcard_roles`

Comment: may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686516/db-schema-of-a-role-based-access-control